# Invalid values in an array on executing for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

I am new to R and stuck up in a very naive thing. I am getting 'NA' values in count array after executing following code:

```
i=1
j=2
l=1
count=0
while(j<length(positions)){
  a=positions[i]
  b=positions[j]
  for(k in a:b){
    if(y$feature[k]==x$feature[l]){
      count[l]=count[l]+1
    }
  }
  i=i+2
  j=j+2
  l=l+1
}
```

For reference, y and x data frames are as follows:

**y data frame**

```
 positions   id  feature     

      1       1    45128
      2       1    28901
      3       1    48902
      .       .
      .       .
      .       .
      .       .
     2344     1    45579
     2345     2    37689
     2346     2    45547
     .        .
     .        .
     5677     2    12339
     5678     3    98034
     5679
     .
     .
```

**x dataframe** :

```
id     feature

 1      28901
 2      23498
 3      98906
 .        .
 .        .
 .        .
```

I have inserted the positions in the position array, at the point where new id starts and where it ends

positions is an array consisting of [1,2344,2345,5677,5678,7390,7391,...]. I am incrementing the for loop as elements in position array, i being 1,3,5... j being 2,4,6... If y$feature and x$feature match I increment count[l]

So first feature of x is compared with all features in y with id=1, second feature in x is compared with all features in y with id=2 and so on. When they match, count[l] is incremented. i and j are incremented twice, to make them start with correct positions. *But I just get a valid answer for count[1], rest all values are NA.

Please tell a reason why this happens and a valid way to do this using the loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are trying to add a nonexistent value `count[l]` to `1`.  You start out with `count<-0`, so `count` is of length one.  There is no `count[2]`, so a reference to `count[2]` returns `NA`.  Then (assuming `l = 2` in your loop), `NA + l` returns `NA`.

If you initialize `count<-rep(0,length(positions))` this particular problem will go away.

Meanwhile, you can vectorize your operations quite a lot.  I believe you can replace the k-loop with

```
 count[l] <-  sum(y$feature[a:b]==x$feature[l])
```

for one example.